# I have many copies of a file (foo.php) in multiple directories that I want to execute from a single PHP instantce

Tags: php, linux, batch-file, cpanel

I have many copies of a file (foo.php) in multiple directories that I want to execute from a single PHP instance (trigger.php) with either a fixed delay between each execution of foo.php, or waiting for each foo.php to finish.

I am trying to avoid having multiple copies of the fairly intensive maintenance script foo.php running simultaneously on a CPanel server creating crippling processor loads.

Note that the directory structure varies.

Example:

```
 me@my [~]# trigger.php
```

executes

```
 home/somesub1/dir/foo.php
 home/somesub2/dir/foo.php
 home/somothersub1/somesub2/dir/foo.php
      ~~      ~~
 home/~/somesubN/dir/foo.php
```

There are over 200 instances of foo.php, so I want to avoid actually listing the directories individually in the script.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: are they all actually the same identical file? If so, why do you need multiple copies of it?

Comment: Similar, but not identical. Each foo.php opens a unique mysql database name, but the operations are all the same. So, each file has a unique database, user, and password as part of the file. The file also executes additional files in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I could think of is to use find and awk. Then run it inside your trigger.php file:

```
echo exec('find ./ -name foo.php | awk \'{print "php " $1}\' | sh');
```

I believe that trigger.php is in the parent/root directory of your foo.php scripts.

Using PHP5's DirectoryIterator is another option, but you have to iterate through each subdirectories and use a conditional statement.